# How to destroy Croppie jQuery existing instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop, croppie

I've using [Croppie jQuery](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) Library for crop a image but facing a problem when it will create multiple instances.

I've found no documentation about destroy instance.

```
function initCrop() {
    var $uploadCrop;
    $('#image_crop').destroy();
    $uploadCrop = $('#image_crop').croppie({
        viewport: {
            width: WIDTH,
            height: HEIGHT,
            type: 'square'
        },
        boundary: {
            width: 798,
            height: 480
        },
        exif: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$('#image_crop').croppie('destroy');
```

For more detail refer [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/).

Comment: oh my days, where were you an hour ago, been trying to get this to work for what feels like an eternity!!